# Implementing Pigeonhole Sort in Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

What is the simplest implementation of *Pigeonhole* Sort in Java? An array of array-lists is ideal, but Java makes this difficult if one wants to remain type-safe. Both an array of arrays or an array-list of array-lists can be used, but are somewhat awkward. I was wondering if there was a general recommendation for what data structure is best.

Comment: I would use a `LinkedList<T>` since this performs insertion in *O(1)* whereas the amortized cost of an `ArrayList<T>` insertion is *O(log n)*

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you want to achieve the theoretical computational complexity of pigeonhole sort, you should use a `LinkedList<T>` and not an `ArrayList<T>`. Many people forget that the *amortized cost* of insertion in an `ArrayList<T>` is *O(log n)* with *n* the number of elements in the list.

As you point out, there is a problem with creating an array of a generic(-dependent) type. But you can circumvent this using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8559232/67579).

So say `n` is the number of keys and `f` is a function calculating the *key* (maps to an integer between `0` and `n-1` (inclusive)) on which we want to sort, then the (inline sorting) algorithm in *Java 8* (with functional programming) looks like:

```
public static<T> void pigeonholeSort (T[] tosort, Function<T,Integer> f, int n) {
    LinkedList<T>[] holes = (LinkedList<T>[]) new LinkedList[n];
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        holes[i] = new LinkedList<T>();
    }
    for(T t : tosort) {
        holes[f.apply(t)].add(t);
    }
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for(T t : holes[i]) {
            tosort[j++] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

You can run this code for instance with:

```
String[] toSort = new String[] {"Foo","Bar","Baz","Fubar","Qux"};
pigeonholeSort(toSort,x -> (Integer) (x.charAt(0)-'A'),26);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(toSort));
```

(on condition you only use strings that start with an uppercase Roman letter).