# Combining a static array with a dynamic ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, static

I want to combine a static array (such as `int[]`) with a dynamic array such as `ArrayList<String>`

For example, I know the count of houses: 10 (fixed), but I don't know the count of humans who live in a house. This count will also change dynamically, like a `List`.

Is there any option to create a datatype which can fulfill both criteria?

Comment: So you want an array of arraylist? Something like in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559092/create-an-array-of-arraylists

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayList` is a dynamicly sized data structure backed by an array. It sounds to me like you could have an array of `House` where each `House` has a `List<Human>` field.

```
House[] homes = new House[10];
```

and a class like

```
class House {
    private List<Human> people = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Human> getPeople() {
        return people;
    }
}
```

then to get the total count of people in those homes you might use something like

```
int count = 0;
for (House h : homes) {
    count += h.getPeople().size();
}
```

Comment: `Arrays.stream(homes).mapToInt(h -> h.getPeople().size()).sum();`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
ArrayList<String>[] house = new ArrayList[15];
for (int x = 0; x < house.length; x++) {
  house[x] = new ArrayList<String>();
}
house[0].add("Pete");
house[0].add("Marta");
house[1].add("Dave");
System.out.println(house[0]);
System.out.println(house[1]);
```

out:

```
[Pete, Marta]
[Dave]
```

..i used this [Create an Array of Arraylists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559092/create-an-array-of-arraylists)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays is worth checking

Comment: The first line compiles for me as is.