# Variable number of list (ArrayList) as an argument to method

Tags: java, arrays, collections

There is a way in Java to handle variable number of String arguments like

```
public void returnString(String...args){
     //some code
}
// calling it
returnString("abc","def","klm")
```

I wanted to know if the same can be applied to Collections. 

If it does not, what is the alternative. I read that array of List is not possible, so wondering how this might work.

```
//Sample code of what I am trying to do
public void returnList(List...args){
    //some code
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried it?

Comment: The varargs feature is applicable for any type, including collections. Who says it isn't?

Comment: It is called varargs   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html   or methods with variable arity http://www.java-tips.org/variable-arity-methods.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where is problem.... But here is example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

  public static void tryIt(List... lists) {
    System.out.println("You insert " + lists.length + " lists.");
  }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<String> listStrings = new ArrayList<>();
      listStrings.add("TEST");
      List<Integer> listInteger = new ArrayList<>();
      listInteger.add(1);
      tryIt(listStrings);
      tryIt(listStrings, listInteger);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
You insert 1 lists.
You insert 2 lists.
```

---

Access to arrays example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
  public static void tryIt(List... lists) {
    System.out.println("You insert " + lists.length + " lists.");
    if (lists.length>2)
      for (Object obj : lists[2]) {
        System.out.println(obj);
      }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> listStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    listStrings.add("TEST");
    List<Integer> listInteger = new ArrayList<>();
    listInteger.add(1);
    List<String> anotherStringList = new ArrayList<>();
    anotherStringList.add("First value.");
    anotherStringList.add("Second value.");
    anotherStringList.add("Third value.");
    tryIt(listStrings);
    tryIt(listStrings, listInteger);
    tryIt(listInteger, listStrings, anotherStringList);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
You insert 1 lists.
You insert 2 lists.
You insert 3 lists.
First value.
Second value.
Third value.
```

Comment: In tryIt method suppose if I had to access a specific list, how can I do it..list[2]?

Answer (score 1):

In [JLS §15.12.4.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.4.2)

> If the method being invoked is a variable arity method m, it necessarily has n > 0 formal parameters. The final formal parameter of m necessarily has type T[] for some T, and m is necessarily being invoked with k ≥ 0 actual argument expressions.

So the type will be an array of `T`. In your first example `returnString(String...args)`, it is `String[]`. In your second example `returnList(List...args)`, it is `List[]`.

You can of course have arrays of `List`s in Java.

Now, if you want in your method body a `List` instead of an array for `args`, then the *varargs* won't help you, but you can build that list with `Arrays.asList(args)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559092/create-an-array-of-arraylists