# I can't understand ArrayList[]= new Arraylist[<size>]; declaration.

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

```
ArrayList[] arr = new ArrayList[5];

for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
arr[i]= sc.nextInt();
}
```

Now, to add a given value to a given index I can do:

```
arr[index].add(value);
```

but how do I delete a value at a given index?

arr[index].remove(); does not work. It say no method found for remove()

Comment: Did you mean to create an array of `ArrayList`? Or just one `ArrayList`?

Comment: here just one ArrayList

Comment: You are creating an array of ArrayLists, probably not what you want. Try `ArrayList arr = new ArrayList()` or `int[] arr = new int[5]`

Comment: Then you want something like `ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(5);`

Comment: thank you. that helped but then what's the difference between 

     ArrayList arr = new ArrayList(); 
    
     ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>(5); 
    
and
    
     List arr= new ArrayList(); 

it's confusing after reading manywhere

Comment: It's confusing that you can't do any research yourself. [Java - declaring from Interface type instead of Class](//stackoverflow.com/q/3383726) // [Java - declaring from Interface type instead of Class](//stackoverflow.com/q/3383726)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use square brackets with your `ArrayList`. Lists are not arrays.

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(5);
```

Add to it with

```
list.add(sc.nextInt());
```

Remove from it with

```
list.remove(index);
```

Comment: can you please explain the difference between ArrayList[] and ArrayList<> declaration?

Comment: Square brackets mean an array of that type.  `ArrayList[]` means an array of ArrayLists.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createArrays)

> "You cannot create arrays of parameterized types"

If requirement is list which further contain list ([refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559092/create-an-array-of-arraylists)), then

```
    List<ArrayList<String>> hs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Welcome");
        list.add(" here");
        hs.add(list);
    }
```

Moreover the working mode of your example will be like:

```
        ArrayList[] arr = new ArrayList[5];
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            if (arr[i] == null) {
                arr[i] = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            arr[i].add(21);
        }
```