# How to make 2 dimensional array containing lists

Tags: java, arrays

I've got a type `Package`, and I want to make something like a rubic's cube. I want to make the floor with a 2-dimensional array and each entry will hold a list (3D).

Making my 2D array

```
Package[][] floor = new Package[x][y];
```

And I've got my List of package, and want to make something like this

```
floor[i][j]= (new ArrayList <Package>()); in a loop
```

Can someone explain why I've got the error message:

> "Cannot convert Package to ArrayList Package"

On my lessons teacher said, I can do something like this.

Comment: Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is declared to store `Package` type objects.
I assume that you want to store `Lists` of `Package` objects in that array.

I found answer on Stack which tells that you cannot create arrays of parameterized objects. It means that you are unable to create array of lists.

Guy who answered thst question shows example of how to create `ArrayList` of `ArrayLists`. Using that example you should be able to create what you want.
You have to create 2D `ArrayList` of `Lists`.

[Link to answer on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559092/create-an-array-of-arraylists)