# Is it possible to create array of suppliers in Java?

Tags: java, java-8

Can I create array of suppliers? This doesn't compile somewhy:

```
Supplier<String>[] x = new Supplier<String>[] {
    () -> "f"
};
```

Comment: Better yet, use a List. Generics and arrays don't mix well because of the different approaches to variance

Comment: ...or if you could explain what restricts you to use an array instead of a `List`?

Comment: @Michael: The linked duplicate is really **not relevant** to this question. The OP asked for the array -> you suggested a List -> you linked a duplicate about creating an array of Lists. If the question should be closed as a duplicate, please refer to a more relevant existing question such as a generic array or array of lambda expressions creation.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis No. It's an exact duplicate. The problem is how to create a `Foo<Bar>[]`. Whether that's `Supplier<String>[]` or `ArrayList<String>[]`, it doesn't matter. The problem is the same. And we don't need a question for every single built-in type which takes a single generic type parameter

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis "you suggested a List -> you linked a duplicate about creating an array of Lists" You list these things as causational, but they are not. You can consider them unrelated. My advice is to use a List. But if they want to ignore my advice, then the linked duplicate has plenty of other suggestions.

Comment: @Michael "No. It's an exact duplicate." - Linking an exact duplicate would eventually lead the OP to the better solution since answers in questions about generics used in the array always suggest using a List instead. Moreover, you really don't know if the OP is not limited by either internal design or external API. The linked duplicate is incorrect, IMHO.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis "*since answers in questions about generics used in the array **always** suggest using a List*" Here are [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28588120/1898563), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8559232/1898563), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17512961/1898563) answers in the linked duplicate that directly contradict that statement. "*Moreover, you really don't know if the OP is not limited by either internal design or external API.*" Irrelevant. The linked duplicate shows solutions involving lists and arrays, so all cases are covered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create an array of raw `Supplier`:

```
Supplier<String>[] x = new Supplier[] {
    () -> "f"
};
```

It's not possible to instantiate a generic array.

Comment: .. and then good luck with `Supplier<String>[] x = new Supplier[]{ () -> "f", () -> 1 };`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this.  But it would be best to use a List.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Supplier<String>[] sups = new Supplier[]{()->"A", ()->"B", ()->"C"};

for (Supplier<String> s : sups) {
    System.out.println(s.get());
}
```

prints

```
A
B
C
```

This would be my preferred way of doing it.  The List returned by `List.of` will be immutable.

```
List<Supplier<String>> sups = List.of(()->"A", ()->"B", ()->"C");
```