# How to create an array of List<String>

Tags: java, arraylist

I use following code to create an array of `List<String`>, but the compiler complains `generic array creation`:

`List<String>[] array = new List<String>[10];`

Also, I would like to convert a list of `List<String>`, the compiler also comlains `generic array creation` with the following code:

```
        List<List<String>> results = new ArrayList<>();
        results.stream().toArray(List<String>[]::new);
```

I would like to ask how to create an array of `List<String>`, and how to convert `List<List<String>>`  to an array of `List<String>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a generic array in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java)

Comment: Why? Why not a `List<List<String>>`? More, err, generic that way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create an Array of ArrayLists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559092/how-can-i-create-an-array-of-arraylists)

Comment: Can you give some example, what you mean by converting List<List<String>> to List<String>?

Comment: @GauravJeswani I would like to convert List<List<String>> to an array of List<String>, this are two cases to demonstrate my question.

Comment: @Tom If you _really_ need to, you can do: `List<?>[] arr = results.stream().toArray(List<?>[]::new)`, cast the result to `List<String>[]` and suppress the warning.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Does this help? [Creating a Generic Array in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-generic-array)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you can't, Java arrays don't support generic types.

There are very few cases where you can't use a `List<List<String>>` instead of an array of `List<String>`. Try that first and come back if you can't do that.

Basically, your choices are make an array of `Object`, and cast the elements to `(List<String>)` when you access them, or make an array of `List`, and again cast to `(List<String>)` if you need to.

Or make a wrapper around the array that will do the casting for you. Which is what a `List<List<String>>` is, so you're back to that question - why not do that?

Comment: Yes, in practice, i would use List<List<String>>, I just come across such a problem, and would like to know how to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Array of generic type are not supported in java.
Instead if you create an array like

List[] array = new List[10];
Than it will work.

Please refer the below question for more details:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java#:~:text=It's%20because%20Java's%20arrays%20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927391/whats-the-reason-i-cant-create-generic-array-types-in-java#:%7E:text=It%27s%20because%20Java%27s%20arrays%20)

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this. Just omit the generic type in the `toArray` method.  The suppress warnings removes the compiler's type safety warning (you may get a runtime class cast exception if the resulting types don't match since the types are erased).  But in this case, it isn't a problem.

```
List<List<String>> results = new ArrayList<>(
        List.of(List.of("ABC", "DEF"), List.of("GHI", "JKL")));

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<String>[] array = results.stream().toArray(List[]::new);
for (List<String> lst : array) {
    System.out.println(lst);
}

String a = array[0].get(1);
System.out.println(a);
```

prints

```
[ABC, DEF]
[GHI, JKL]
DEF
```

Contrast the following using the same data and see what happens when you try to get an `"Integer"` from a list in the array.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Integer>[] array = results.stream().toArray(List[]::new);
Integer a = array[0].get(1);  // class cast exception!!
System.out.println(a);
```

And finally, you can also do it sans streams.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<String>[] arr = new ArrayList[2];
arr[0] = new ArrayList<>(List.of("ABC","DEF"));
arr[1] = new ArrayList<>(List.of("GHI","JKL"));

String a = arr[1].get(0);
System.out.println(a);
```

prints

```
GHI
```