# How to create an array of type Generic type List<List<Integer>> in Java

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to create an array of list of list of Integers

```
List<List<Integer>>[] numList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>[10];
```

When I compile this code I get an error:

> Cannot create a generic array of ArrayList<List> Type
> mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to List

What is the right syntax of doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create an Array of ArrayLists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559092/how-can-i-create-an-array-of-arraylists)

Comment: If you really want to, there's a hack: `class ListOfListOfInts extends ArrayList<List<Integer>> {} List<List<Integer>>[] numList = new ListOfListOfInts[10];` but I would strongly recommend using a `List` instead of an array.

Comment: @AhmedNabil I checked that solution first, it was not working

Comment: @aioobe
Type mismatch: cannot convert from ListOfListOfInts[] to List<List<Integer>>[]
Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to List<Integer>
Even casting it is not working

Comment: You must have messed up when copying: https://ideone.com/oYGFn1

Comment: Generics and arrays don't play well together. Don't use an array.

Answer (score 1):

although unadvised as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559092/how-can-i-create-an-array-of-arraylists)

```
List<List<Integer>>[] arrOfGeneric = (List<List<Integer>>[]) new ArrayList[5];
```

Answer (score -2):

This works:

```
List<List<Integer>>[] numList = (List<List<Integer>>[]) new List[10];
```